# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 20, Size: 20

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a lz78 code as a school project, but I keep getting this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index:
>   20, Size: 20

Here is the code:

```
public class LZ88 {
    ArrayList input = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList stored = new ArrayList();
    Iterator counter = input.iterator();
    int count=0;
    int lz78(String x)
    {
        int length=x.length();
        for(int i=0;i<x.length();i++)
        {
            input.add(x.charAt(i));
        }
        for(int i=0;i<=input.size(); i++)
        {
            if(stored.contains(input.get(i))==true)
            {
                String str ;
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append(input.get(i));
                sb.append(input.get(++i));
                str=sb.toString();
                while(stored.contains(str)==true)
                {
                    sb.append(input.get(++i));
                    str=sb.toString();

                }
                stored.add(str);
                System.out.println(stored);
            }
            else
            {
                stored.add(x.charAt(i));
                System.out.println(stored);
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String x ="abaababaababbbbbbbba";
        LZ88 ob = new LZ88();
        ob.lz78(x);
    }

}
```

Comment: What line does this error occur? What is the stack trace? Please [edit] your answer and add the stacktrace.

Comment: There is no point in comparing a boolean value to true, as you do. Whatever it's value actually is, is the same whether you compare it or not.

e.g. `if(stored.contains(input.get(i))==true)` is identical functionally to `if(stored.contains(input.get(i)))`

Answer (score 3):

Replace `for(int i=0;i<=input.size(); i++)` with `for(int i=0;i<input.size(); i++)`

Comment: @Mohamed Mamdoh If my Answer have catered to your Question please accept the Answer by clicking on the hollow check mark beside my Answer which is just below the VoteDown arrow so the check mark turns green . How to accept: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work